# Can a dominance matrix be used for ranking?

Tags: matrices, discrete-mathematics

I have only seen competition scenarios for an application for dominance matrix so far, as shown in the screenshot below.

[image: Example]

Can a dominance matrix be possibly used for a ranking of exam marks perhaps?
I am thinking of a scenario where 5 students sit the maths exam once, and after their exams are marked, their ranking is displayed by a dominance matrix.

Suppose that the number of marks obtained by student A is highest, followed by that of student B, C, D then E. The dominance matrix for this would be
A ‘1’ in row A and column B would mean that student A obtained higher marks than student B.

[image: example]

Any feedback would be appreciated.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

A dominance matrix shows you the wins and losses of a number of teams against others. So for example Team A beat team B,C,D but not team E, Team B lost to team A and C but beat teams D and E and so on. You see how Team A beat team B but not team E. But team B (who lost to team A) beat Team E (which Team A could not beat although having already beat Team B). Thus dominance matrices can determine how to rank tricky scenarios like this. But in your case, these students already have a ranking. A dominance matrix would not be used to represent this as you can't have a score that beat another student's score but loses to a different student's score. You have set number scores and that ranking is already determined.